# Remove all the occurences that contain a part of the initial string

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a list of string that contains for example the following items:

`0$1, 0$2, 0$5, 1$1, 1$8`

My will is remove the other items with $1 if one already exists.
In that example, the expected output would be:

`0$1, 0$2, 0$5, 1$8`

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this, with LINQ or anything else, rather than doing something like this?

```
For Each str As String In ddlElecDBFilter.SelectedItemsList
    Dim currentString As String = str
    'DO A FOR EACH LOOP on the other elements (starting from the current index + 1 and delete them 

Next
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is tagged as C# but your code is in a different language (looks like VB?). What language do you (want to) use?

Comment: yes sorry, i've added VB.NET. But if someone comes up with a C# solution it'seasy to translate

Comment: Make a new list, and add items from your list of string if they are not already in the new list. What is the approximate size of the list - tens, hundreds, or more strings?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would say the size of the list is tens maximum.
That's probably the best solution, Thank you. i could try to do something like this

Comment: @solrin Actually, using a Dictionary(Of String, String) where the first string is the part that must be unique might be easier. The documentation for [Dictionary.ContainsKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey) has an example that pretty much does what you want.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Sorted Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Do you only want to keep the first "$1" regardless of position, and are only concerned with "$1"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a "cleaner" way to do this:

```
Dim input As String = "0$1, 0$2, 0$5, 1$1, 1$8"

Dim uniqueValues As New List(Of String)
input.Split(", ".ToCharArray, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
    .Where(Function(x) x.Contains("$")) _
    .Select(Function(y) New KeyValuePair(Of String, String)(y.Substring(y.IndexOf("$")), y)) _
    .ToList() _
    .ForEach(Sub(pair)
                 If Not uniqueValues.Any(Function(x) x.EndsWith(pair.Key)) Then
                     uniqueValues.Add(pair.Value)
                 End If
             End Sub)
Dim output As String = String.Join(", ", uniqueValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said C# was acceptable, here my answer is for C#. If you have trouble translating to VB.Net, I can add that.

I would not say that LINQ is cleaner, but it is short. When you need to accumulate items, `Aggregate` is the method to use. When you need to keep some type of state while processing, `Aggregate` with a `ValueTuple` (or some other container) allows you to preserve a value while processing.

If `ss` contains your `List<string>`, then `ans` will contain the processed strings:

```
var ans = ss.Select(s => s.Split(", ")
            .Aggregate((ans: Enumerable.Empty<string>(), seen: false), // accumulate result in ans, track whether $1 has been seen
                       (ans_seen, item) => ans_seen.seen
                                            ? (item.EndsWith("$1") ? ans_seen : (ans_seen.ans.Append(item), ans_seen.seen))
                                            : (ans_seen.ans.Append(item), item.EndsWith("$1"))
                      )
            .ans.Join(", ")) // string extension method that encapsulates String.Join
            .ToList();
```

This uses an obvious string extension method to encapsulate `String.Join`.

I would say it is better to create a function that uses looping and just use LINQ for the `List` processing:

```
public static class StringExt {
    public static string KeepOnlyFirstDollarOne(this string s) {
        var seen = false;
        var resultList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in s.Split(", ")) {
            if (seen) {
                if (!item.EndsWith("$1"))
                    resultList.Add(item);
            }
            else {
                resultList.Add(item);
                seen = item.EndsWith("$1");
            }
        }
        return String.Join(", ", resultList);
    }
}
```

Then getting an answer is as simple as:

```
var ans = ss.Select(s => s.KeepOnlyFirstDollarOne()).ToList();
```